# Celery: one task at a time

Tags: python, celery

I am using `celery` in my Python web project. I have 2 pages on which 2 different long running functions are there as tasks. Both these functions have or share a common queue.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

When a task runs or is started from any page, if the user switches to another page and tries to start the task from that page (default behavior: this tasks gets added to the queue) I want to display a message "one task is already in progress, try after some time" and thereby user will have to click the button again later to initiate the task.

I tried setting `--concurrency=1`

Are there any more settings that I need to set?

Answer (score 0):

Celery creates unique task_id for every task it executes and stores(if backend is configured) the status in the backend. For your case, either store task_id in any of the databases corresponding to that user and for every request, query the task status and send that to frontend. Or you can directly send the task_id to frontend and send it with every request and check the status. For checking the status of any task_id, you can use the following:

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
res = AsyncResult("your-task-id")
res.ready()
```